# .net core 6 jwt token mocking

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-core-6.0

I am looking for a tutorial on how to mock authentication tokens for .net core 6 web services. Some years ago, at a previous job, I looked up how to do this with .net 3 and got it to work. But 6 removed the startup.cs file and seems to have shifted things around quite a bit. There are very few examples of doing this for 6.

I am in the process of creating a series of unit tests for the endpoints in a new web application. I am starting over from bare bones. Here is the code example. I know that it is possible to recreate the Startup.cs file, but for the time being I would prefer to do it without that. Are there any examples of this for a .net 6 specific architecture?

```cs
 internal class DssiApiTest : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
    {
        private readonly string _environment;

        public DssiApiTest(string environment = "Development")
        {
            _environment = environment;
        }
        
        protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseEnvironment(_environment);
            var settings = new ApiSettings();

            // Add mock/test services to the builder here
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddScoped(sp =>
                {
                    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .UseInMemoryDatabase("Tests")
                    .UseApplicationServiceProvider(sp)
                    .Options;
                    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options, 
                                                                  MakeMockTenantService(),
                                                                  (Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<ApiSettings>)settings))
                    {
                        context.PartCustomers.Add(CreatePartCustomer(1, 1));
                        context.PartCustomers.Add(CreatePartCustomer(2, 1));
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                        // Replace SQLite with in-memory database for tests
                        return options;
                });
            });

            return base.CreateHost(builder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't find anything on ‎how to mock authentication tokens for .net core 6‎, but according to ‎"[Mocking OIDC Auth while integration testing ASP.Net‎](https://github.com/tarwn/blogexample-aspnetcore/blob/master/dotnet-6/Sample-OIDC-WebApp/IntegrationTests/Utility/CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs)", it doesn't seem to be much different from .net 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to what I needed to do. I have not been able to fully test it yet, however, because I am running into another issue that is throwing an error. Will have to ask another question for that one. Here is what I have so far. If anyone can elaborate or correct this please feel free to do so. Like I said, I have not fully tested it and don't want to lead others astray. Will update once I have it worked out.

I added a new TestAuthHandler to the virtual client that returns a mock auth result like so :

```cs
using var application = new TestWebApplicationFactory();
            var client = application.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddAuthentication("Test")
                        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(
                            "Test", options => { });
                });
            })
            .CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            });
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Test");
```

Here is the code for the TestAuthHandler

```cs
public class TestAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        public TestAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test user") };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Test");

            var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }
```